# Why isn't my div block staying in the same place?

Tags: html, css

In the first pic, you can see the blue block is centered in the grey background. It's how I want it to be. Fine. [image: first pic] However, in the second pic it did not move when the window scaled up. The blue block is the `#bodyCenterCont` and it's inside of the `#bodyCont`. If you need more code, please let me know. I've tried all the different positions and margins. I don't have a full understanding of relevant, fixed, and absolute.  [image: second pic]

### Heading ##CODE:

```css
*** The new CSS Reset - version 1.2.0 (last updated 23.7.2021) ***/
/* Remove all the styles of the "User-Agent-Stylesheet", except for the 'display' property */

*:where(:not(iframe, canvas, img, svg, video):not(svg *)) {
  all: unset;
  display: revert;
}


/* Preferred box-sizing value */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*
Remove list styles (bullets/numbers)
in case you use it with normalize.css */

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* For images to not be able to exceed their container */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Removes spacing between cells in tables */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/* Revert the 'white-space' property for textarea elements on Safari */

textarea {
  white-space: revert;
}

#parentCont {
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#welcomeCont {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
  height: 150px;
}

#welcomeText {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#bodyCont {
  background-image: linear-gradient(grey, black);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#bodyCenterCont {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentCont">
  <div id="welcomeCont">
    <p id="welcomeText">Legend & Myth</p>
  </div>

  <div id="bodyCont">
    <div id="bodyCenterCont">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without your code. Preferably as a [mcve]

Comment: The CSS code is in the first picture. I don't really know what other code you would need.

Comment: An image is not code. CSS is pretty meaningless without HTML. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Typing out code from in image is painful and error prone. Imagining HTML even more so

Comment: I put the HTML, I hope it helps.

Comment: Please provide Code as code, not an image! Better still use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to create a [MCVE]. The more effort you put into your question, the more effort will be put into answers

Comment: I put the code into format at the bottom, sir.

Comment: The CSS is still an image. If I want to replicate the issue, I have to type out the CSS from an image. **You** should do that for us.

Comment: I formatted the CSS code, sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
#bodyCenterCont{
position: absolute;
height:400px;
width:350px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background:blue;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you used only margin-left:30%; that's why the container is aligned left.

```
 margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
```

you can use these property to align any content to the center of the page.
I also modified your code you can refer my code snippet.

```css
*** The new CSS Reset - version 1.2.0 (last updated 23.7.2021) ***/
/* Remove all the styles of the "User-Agent-Stylesheet", except for the 'display' property */

*:where(:not(iframe, canvas, img, svg, video):not(svg *)) {
  all: unset;
  display: revert;
}


/* Preferred box-sizing value */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*
Remove list styles (bullets/numbers)
in case you use it with normalize.css */

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* For images to not be able to exceed their container */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Removes spacing between cells in tables */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/* Revert the 'white-space' property for textarea elements on Safari */

textarea {
  white-space: revert;
}

#parentCont {
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#welcomeCont {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));
  height: 150px;
}

#welcomeText {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#bodyCont {
  background-image: linear-gradient(grey, black);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#bodyCenterCont {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top: 8%;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="parentCont">
  <div id="welcomeCont">
    <p id="welcomeText">Legend & Myth</p>
  </div>

  <div id="bodyCont">
    <div id="bodyCenterCont">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```